# What might cause a type mismatch on a init of a splayed table in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to create a new, empty, splayed table:

```
price_data: ([] s:`$(); t:`timestamp$(); o:`float$(); h:`float$(); l:`float$(); c:`float$(); v:`int$())

`:/home/data/price_data/ set price_data
```

I'm getting a type mismatch error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting splayed tables all symbol columns need to be enumerated, otherwise it will throw a type error.

This can be achieved using [.Q.en](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qen-enumerate-varchar-cols), which converts the symbol columns to integral values and a corresponding [sym](https://code.kx.com/q/wp/symfiles/) file containing the symbol values.

Enumerated symbol columns have type 20h instead of type 11h.

```
/ pre enumeration
q)type price_data`s
11h
/ after enumeration
q)type .Q.en[`:.;price_data]`s
20h
/ since we have no symbols in our table an empty sym file is generated
q)get`:sym
`symbol$()
```